# LNK4098: defaultlib "mfc42d.lib" conflicts in Release build

Tags: visual-c++

After several hours of stretching my hairs, I can't figure this out. In Debug version, it is working fine. But in release mode, I am getting this warnings and eventually an runtime error. As far as I know, these libraries are debug versions. Why is my release build looking for these libraries and how can I stop it? FYI, I looked at settings and project files to find a clue in vain.

```
 LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib "mfc42d.lib" conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
 LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib "mfcs42d.lib" conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
 LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib "msvcrtd.lib" conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Comment: Yes, "d" means debug.  You don't want debug libraries in the Release build.  You'll have to find out what code you are linking that was built in the Debug configuration.  Typically a .lib you didn't create.  Old stuff, mfc42 was a long long time ago.  If you have no idea then grep the .libs and .objs for "mfc42d".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to tell without more information why your project is including these. My guess is that you are linking with a debug configuration of some other library, which is pulling in those dependencies.  If you increase the verbosity of the linker settings then it may show you which files are including them.

The fix though is given in the error message. Add `/nodefaultlib:mfc42d.lib/nodefaultlib:mfcs42d.lib  /nodefaultlib:msvcrtd.lib` to the linker arguments.

Comment: Yeah, it was one of the libraries linked in the project. Thanks for your clarification.